# Changing a pandas dataframe format into another format?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, pandas-groupby, influxdb

The given dataframe looks like this:

[image: dataframe.head()]

```
                     sensorA  sensorB  deviceA  deviceB  inputA  inputB  machineA  machineB  flagA  flagB  mainA
Time                                                                                                            
2021-11-26 20:20:00    379.0      0.0      0.0    489.0    0.77    35.0       0.0      51.0  -13.0  230.0    1.6
2021-11-26 20:30:00    344.0      0.0      0.0    143.0    0.76    31.0       0.0      50.0  -11.0  230.0    1.8
```

I want to map this to a the following format separting the individual columns into a combination of Field and attribute.

| Time | Type | attribute | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-26 20:20:00 | sensor | a | 999 |

I have tried mutiple directions to approch this using multi indexing, groupby etc but cant seem to get around on how to exactly impliment this ?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: The names of your columns are like your sample in the real case? Columns ends by A or B, or C, ...?

Comment: `source_type`? Do you mean `type_tag`? Can I safely use `_` as a separator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

If your column names contain `'_'` as separator, you can use:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True).rename(['Type', 'Tag'])
out = df.unstack().rename('Value').reset_index(level=['Type', 'Tag']).sort_index()
```

---

Extract type/tag from column names with a regular expression:

```
types = ['sensor', 'device', 'input', 'machine', 'flag', 'main']
pat = fr"({'|'.join(types)})(.*)"

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.columns.str.extract(pat), 
                                      names=['Type', 'Tag'])
out = df.unstack().rename('Value').reset_index(level=['Type', 'Tag']).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                        Type Tag   Value
Time                                    
2021-11-26 20:20:00   sensor   A  379.00
2021-11-26 20:20:00     flag   B  230.00
2021-11-26 20:20:00     flag   A  -13.00
2021-11-26 20:20:00  machine   B   51.00
2021-11-26 20:20:00  machine   A    0.00
2021-11-26 20:20:00     main   A    1.60
2021-11-26 20:20:00    input   A    0.77
2021-11-26 20:20:00    input   B   35.00
2021-11-26 20:20:00   device   B  489.00
2021-11-26 20:20:00   device   A    0.00
2021-11-26 20:20:00   sensor   B    0.00
2021-11-26 20:30:00    input   A    0.76
2021-11-26 20:30:00   device   A    0.00
2021-11-26 20:30:00    input   B   31.00
2021-11-26 20:30:00  machine   A    0.00
2021-11-26 20:30:00   sensor   B    0.00
2021-11-26 20:30:00  machine   B   50.00
2021-11-26 20:30:00     flag   A  -11.00
2021-11-26 20:30:00   sensor   A  344.00
2021-11-26 20:30:00     flag   B  230.00
2021-11-26 20:30:00   device   B  143.00
2021-11-26 20:30:00     main   A    1.80
```

Comment: Okay , this is really hellful, i think i can work from this. Thanks a lot for help and guidance, really appreatiate it.